# To find the value of x in a metal chloride MClx

Tags: physical-chemistry, concentration, mole

A solution containing 0.1 mol of a metal chloride MCl<sub>x</sub> requires 500 ml of 0.8 M AgNO<sub>3</sub> solution for complete precipitation. The value of **x** is:

(a) 1 
(b) 2 
(c) 4 
(d) 3

Please answer with an explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\ce{MCl_x + xAgNO3 -> xAgCl + M(NO3)_x}$$

$500$ mL of $0.8$ M is $0.4$ mol, so the mole ratio between $\ce{MCl_x}$ and $\ce{AgNO3}$ used is $1:4$.

From the equation above, the mole ratio is $1:x$.

Therefore, $1:x=1:4 \implies x=4$.

Comment: While we appreciate your contribution to the site, it would be preferable to not answer questions, that do not comply with our [homework policy](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/).

Comment: @Martin-マーチン Sorry, noted.